# Order duplicated registries and count them (give a number to each registry)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe you could lend me a hand

I have this table

```
Name
----
Pablo
Cris
Pablo
Pablo
Cris
```

I need a query that results in

```
Name
----
Cris     1
Cris     2
Pablo    1
Pablo    2
Pablo    3
```

I know about order the result and about finding duplicates with having count, but is there a way to enumerate them like this?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Window Functions to do this.  The ROW_NUMBER function will put an incrementing counter on every row, in the order specified by the Order  By clause within the window.  The Partition By clause will start the counter over within each different partition.

```
SELECT NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME)
FROM table
```

Comment: Just a note. is the comma (just before `ORDER BY`) supported in SQL Server? Oracle rejects it.

Comment: the post is tagged SQL server.  Do you need a PLSQL solution?  doh.  Comma is wrong in either case.  Sorry -- fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much!